# Efficient MySQL query to compute percentage

Tags: mysql

I am newbie to MySQL and coming from Oracle background. I have a SQL query that computes the total count and percentage for type in a table.

For example:

```
SELECT type,count(*) count_by_type ,a.tot total, (COUNT(*)*100/a.total) percent 
FROM xyz
JOIN (select count(*) tot from xyz)a
GROUP by type
HAVING type = 'abc';
```

This query is doing a self-join. Is there a simpler way to achieve the same?

Comment: Define "simpler" please. This query is not complicated at all. PS: why do you use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`?

Comment: Your query is simple enough. Not every query can be written in one or two lines of code...

Comment: would using WHERE make it any faster ?

Comment: Since `type` is a field in your table, you may use `WHERE` instead of `HAVING`. It will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `SELF JOIN` here and `HAVING` clause. try it as:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO @var_total FROM xyz;

SELECT type, count(1) AS count_by_type,
        @var_total total,
        (COUNT(1)*100/@var_total) AS percent
FROM xyz a
WHERE type = 'abc';
GROUP by type;
```

Comment: Nope. This query would produce another resultset. Not an answer

Comment: Your query will produce a MySQL error since `total` is not a field in table `xyz`

Comment: Nested query in `SELECT` part is unlikely better than in `JOIN`, since it will be performed N times

Comment: `count(1)` isn't better than `coun(*)`

Comment: Now better, but still - why `COUNT(1)`?!?!?

Comment: Using COUNT(*) or COUNT(1) is exactly the same. [Read explanation here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1)

Comment: What you are suggesting has two queries. But the code which is going to call is PHP, can we include club multiple queries without using stored procedure and also is WHERE going to make it any faster ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT type,count(1) count_by_type ,(select count(1) from xyz) total,
(count_by_type*100/total) percent  FROM xyz WHERE type = 'abc';
```

Comment: I'm sure this query will be less efficient - subquery in `SELECT` clause will be performed N times

Comment: Not if it is cached, but I don`t know for sure.

Comment: mysql cannot cache nested queries

Comment: Your query will probably compute `total` for each record.